# Unable to publish items to Sitecore from custom web api called via console app

Tags: sitecore

I am using Sitecore 7.2. We have a console app that is scheduled to execute every 24 hours. This app gets data from an external database and simply calls a web api service at Sitecore end to which it passes this data. The web api has code that makes use of native Sitecore api to move this data to Sitecore and publish this migrated data to web database at the same time.
While the data gets moved to Sitecore (i.e. master db) successfully, the publishing fails i.e. it simply does not publish the items but doesn't throw an error. After analysis, I noticed that if I call the same service via browser by typing in the url of the web api method since it is a http get method, it publishes the items successfully. I noticed that a certain cookie gets passed when api is called via browser which all other non browser clients such as my console app do not send and which is required to trigger the publishing.
I am now thinking that Sitecore publish method has some security built in that prevents publishing from not Sitecore environment (since web api is not exactly a Sitecore site). I am now thinking of using the native Sitecore web api to publish the items or adding the items to both master and web at the same time. What are the other options available to me keeping in mind that I need to publish immediately after the data has been migrated?

Comment: https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Sitecore_PowerShell_console.aspx

Comment: To me it also sounds like a security issue. You could try to add a using(new SecurityDisabler()) {..} around the code that does the publish to see if that makes a difference. If you establish that this is indeed security related you can make provisions to deal with that in a better way (remember that the SecurityDisabler has no place in production code) ... if there is no difference then at least security can be ruled out...